# How to convert a crosstab back into raw data in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table : four computer brands A~D，and battery life data like this:

```
A   B   C    D
17  8   6   24
10  4   15  12
13  21  8   15
```

I want to convert it back to raw data like this:

```
months  brand
17      A
10      A
13      A
8       B
4       B
21      B
6       C
15      C
8       C
24      D
12      D
15      D
```

I do a few searches, and still don't know how .Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Please don't post your code or data as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's [hard to read](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `DataFrame.melt()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df

Out[]:
    A   B   C   D
0  17   8   6  24
1  10   4  15  12
2  13  21   8  15

In []:
df.melt(var_name='brand', value_name='months')

Out[]:
   brand  months
0      A      17
1      A      10
2      A      13
3      B       8
4      B       4
5      B      21
6      C       6
7      C      15
8      C       8
9      D      24
10     D      12
11     D      15
```

Comment: Thank you,that's what I am looking for .